# How to get the texture to respect the UV unwrap after attributing the material in geometry nodes

Tags: materials, uv, geometry-nodes

I'm trying get water droplets effect using geometry nodes, however I'm encountering a material problem, I don't know what I'm missing in my nodes setup to give the model information about UV map I have of the can.

Model in material preview
[image: image of the model in material preview]

Without geometry nodes
[image: image without geometry nodes]

Geometry Nodes setup
[image: geometry nodes setup]

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's difficult to see what is your problem, so could you post your .blend here : https://blend-exchange.com/